# Adding classes to custom Angular Components?

Tags: angular

I am trying to allow a user to add any number of classes to the outer HTML of a child component. So lets say there is a component called app-button, with html like:

**app-button.component.html**

```
<button
[ngClass] = {"..."}
[class] = "static classes"
>
{{text}}
</button>
```

I want a user to be able to add any number of classes to this app-button selector, such that it will add classes to the button tag.

For instance, within a parent component, if a user does:

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-button class = "user-class1 user-class2 ..." >
</app-button>
```

I want the app-button HTML to end up like this:

```
<button
[ngClass] = {"..."}
[class] = "static classes user-class1 user-class2"
>
{{text}}
</button>
```

I need some way to do this so that it is not specific to any classname, but works for any class a user would want to add.

Answer (score 0):

**app-button.component.ts**

Add myClasses input variable inside your component class.

```
@Input() myClasses;
```

**app-button.component.html**

```
<button [ngClass]="myClasses" class = "static classes">
  {{text}}
</button>
```

**parent.component.ts**

Create an array for your dynamic css classes.

```
classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

**parent.component.html**

Pass your classes array into app-button component.

```
<app-button [myClasses]="classes">
</app-button>
```